# Multiple projects to improve performance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I started an project in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Store and a thought entered my mind.

Does dividing you total project over smaller library's improve your App? What kind of advantages does it give me to divide my project into smaller ones?

Comment: 'improve' is pretty vague.  Really depends on your implementation as a whole

Comment: i mean like performance wise for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no performance advantages. The advantage comes from the modularity of multiple projects: you can reuse the modules in other projects. Doing this might be a good idea for a large application that has smaller components (library functions, custom controls, business logic, whatever) that might be reused in other applications.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @David What do you mean, what do I mean by that - what do I mean by what? Who's on first? ;-)

Comment: He probably meant me. @David If you need to do a quick fix to, say, your parsing class, you can fix, recompile, and release only that library rather than the entire program.

Comment: @Magus: Yes I meant you. Thanks for the elaboration

Answer (score 1):

If you can generalize parts of your project, e.g. for service methods, controls etc. it makes sense to externalize them into separate DLLs since you can reuse this functionality in further projects more easily.

Comment: It answers the second part of his question